# PyPlot, PyCall Legend Font Size from Julia

Tags: matplotlib, graphics, julia

When I try and change the legend fontsize using PyPlot from julia, I get an error message saying "Pyerror..got an unexpected key word "'fontsize'". This happens when I try both of the standard formulations shown below:

```
ax[:legend](  ("Data", "Model Predictions"),fontsize=4,loc=4 )
ax[:legend](  ("Data", "Model Predictions"),prop={fontsize: "small"},loc=4 )
```

Note that changing fontsize works fine with other objects e.g. xlabel

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
using PyPlot
fig, ax = PyPlot.subplots()
ax[:plot](rand(10), rand(10), label = "Data")
ax[:legend](loc="best", fontsize=4)
```

If not, what versions of Julia, PyPlot, PyCall, and Python are you on?

Answer (score 0):

The help for legend states that:

> prop : None or :class:`matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties` or dict
>       The font properties of the legend. If None (default), the current
>       :data:`matplotlib.rcParams` will be used.

So the prob keyword argument expects a dict with font properties. Dicts is constructed in julia as `[key => val]`. This dict can then contain the properties. The property you would like to set is `size` and not `fontsize` because the prob keyword argument only contains font properties.

```
    ax[:legend](("Data", "Model Predictions"), prop=["size" => "small"], loc=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end the above two suggestions didn't work (I think it's a version issue). But this did:

```
using PyPlot
@pyimport  matplotlib.pyplot as plt
@pyimport matplotlib.font_manager as fm
prop = fm.FontProperties(size=9)
fig, ax = PyPlot.subplots()
ax[:plot](rand(10), rand(10), label = "Data")
ax[:legend](loc="best", prop=prop)
```